# Elasticsearch match_phrase doesn't perform the same as multi_match with type phrase?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having some trouble turning a `match_phrase` query into a `multi_match` query for multiple fields. My original query:

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 50,
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "query" : {
        "match_phrase" : {
          "metadata.description" : "Search Terms"
        }
      },
      "filter" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [ {
            "terms" : {
              "collectionId" : [ "1", "2" ]
            }
          } ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Returns results correctly, but when I rewrite the `match_phrase` piece as a `multi_match` to run against multiple fields:

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 50,
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "query" : {
        "multi_match" : {
          "query" : "Search Terms",
          "fields" : [ "metadata.description", "metadata.title" ],
          "type" : "phrase"
        }
      },
      "filter" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [ {
            "terms" : {
              "collectionId" : [ "1", "2" ]
            }
          } ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am not getting any results. Is there anything obvious I am doing wrong here?

EDIT:

It must be something to do with the filter, as

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 50,
  "query" : {
    "match_phrase" : {
      "metadata.description" : "Search Terms"
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 50,
  "query" : {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query" : "Search Terms",
      "fields" : [ "metadata.description", "metadata.title" ],
      "type" : "phrase"
    }
  }
}
```

both perform as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why, exactly, but not using a `filtered` query, and applying the filter at the top level

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 50,
  "query" : {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query" : "Search Terms",
      "fields" : [ "metadata.description", "metadata.title" ],
      "type" : "phrase"
    }
  },
  "filter" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [ {
        "terms" : {
          "collectionId" : [ "1", "2" ]
        }
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

resolves the problem.